# Как лучше осуществить сохранение введенных данных в БД MySQL?

Tags: javascript, localstorage, html5, mysql

Доброе утро, господа. Есть таблица, где данные, для заполнения этой таблицы, берутся из базы данных MySQL. Но есть одно пустое поле "Комментарии", на котором можно кликнуть мышкой и ввести любой комментарий к любой записи. Сделано это с помощью новой возможности HTML5 <td id="editable" **contenteditable="true"**></td>. Я сначала хотел сохранять комментарии с помощью JavaScript и localstorage, но пришлось отказаться от этого, так как клиент будет работать с приложением на разных компьютерах. Как мне лучше сохранять комментарии в БД MySQL? Для наглядности - http://www.devhelper.ru/parser/

Comment: DB MySQL тут ни причем. перехватывайте событие input  в элементах, складывайте в очередь на запись и отсылайте ajax, [вот пример перехвата события на jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/uebSB/) - все отлично работает.

Comment: ajax, именно ajax

Answer (score 2):

Можно аяксом отсылать на сервер, а там сохранять. Можно использовать Yahoo UI, там у них были объекты таблица и массив данных таблицы и можно гонять между клиентом и сервером, да еще сортировать попутно